# Having single posts appear under the blog homepage and highlight menu items properly?

Tags: single, blog-page

My Wordpress site which has a static frontpage and the blog page assigned to a subpage of a section. My blog's homepage is:

/be-the-first-to-care/first-to-care-blogs/

This works great for the blog page. However when I click through to a single post it breaks out of the hierarchy and appears just as

/blog-post/

The menus and submenus don't highlight properly etc.

Is there a good workaround for this? I'd like single posts to appear at:

/be-the-first-to-care/first-to-care-blogs/blog-post/

Basically I'd like my blog to be the root of any single blog post. Would like this to carry through for category pages etc.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can edit your permalinks like so:

`/be-the-first-to-care/first-to-care-blogs/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%/`

I'm not sure why blog posts work like that, maybe somebody can give you further insight but the above works for me. You can edit your permalinks via:

`Admin Panel -> Settings -> Permalinks`

Then click the "Custom Structure" radio button and fill in the textbox with the above.

Comment: That works for the URLs. However it doesn't "know" that the blog posts fall under the proper menu items. It's not adding the "active" class. Will probably have to hack this in.